# Could not resolve placeholder(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: )

Tags: spring-boot

I can't set properties in the **application.properties** that would then be integrated via **@Value**

```
server.port=8099

spring.data.mongodb.database=mongo-spring

spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=root

#spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.99.100
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.99.109
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017/mongo-spring

#spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true

############################################
#--------reCaptcha Google-----------------
#############################################


#Site key - Use this in the HTML code your site serves to users.
#Secret key - Use this for communication between your site and Google. Be sure to keep it a secret.
apiUrl=https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify


api.prefix=/api/**
header.cors.origins.allow=http://10.0.0.1:8080 , http://10.10.8.2:8080 
header.cors.methods.allow=GET, PUT, POST
```

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration {

    @Value("${api.prefix}")
    private String apiPrefix;

    @Value("${header.cors.origins.allow}")
    private String [] headerCorsOriginsAllow;

    @Value("${header.cors.methods.allow}")
    private String [] headerCorsMethodsAllow;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {

        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping(apiPrefix)
                        .allowedOrigins(headerCorsOriginsAllow)
                        .allowedMethods(headerCorsMethodsAllow);
            }
        };
    }


}
```

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Test set: com.spring.mongo.SpringMongoApplicationTests
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.081
> s <<< FAILURE! - in com.spring.mongo.SpringMongoApplicationTests
> contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'corsGlobalConfiguration': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'api.prefix' in value "${api.prefix}" Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'api.prefix' in value "${api.prefix}"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring.mongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-mongo</name>
  

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <version.mapstruct>1.3.0.Final</version.mapstruct>
        <version.apache.maven.plugins>3.8.1</version.apache.maven.plugins>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.apache.maven.plugins}</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

**Update-1**

I converted the application.properties in the application.in YML format.

An error , disappeared.

But now in the development environment, I can't view the value of a variable by clicking on the @Value expression

And I get another error during an application.

> 2020-08-07 22:35:15.244  WARN 48300 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> to parse configuration class
> [com.spring.mongo.SpringMongoApplication]; nested exception is
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
> [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
> 2020-08-07 22:35:15.262 ERROR 48300 --- [           main]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
> to parse configuration class
> [com.spring.mongo.SpringMongoApplication]; nested exception is
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
> [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I added into pom.xml

- pom.xml

```xml
<build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>config</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Now, I again get the error:

- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Could not resolve placeholder**

Why?

The encoding all project is **UTF-8**.

Everything worked before. Now the **@Value** annotation doesn't work

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: skyho did you just publish your api access keys?

Comment: could you show the class that you are using @Value ${api.prefix} ?

Comment: The keys is not working.